# JavaScript overwrite Object property enumerability still not enumerable

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am learning JavaScript's prototype chain and `for...in` and was wondering if it is possible to overwrite some of the data property of built-in methods. I have the following snippet:

```js
function Parent(name) {
  this.name = name;
}
Parent.prototype.sex = "Male";
function Child(name, age) {
  Parent.call(this, name);
  this.age = age;
}
Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);
Object.defineProperty(Child.prototype, "constructor", {
  value: Child,
  enumerable: false,
});
const person1 = new Child("John", 26);
for (const key in person1) {
  console.log(key);
}
// name
// age
// sex
```

Above is basically setting up a simple inheritance, and the bottom `for...in` iteration works as expected. Most importantly, it was able to find the `sex` property high up in the prototype chain.
I assume that all of these objects have the `Object.prototype` high up in their prototype chains, but the reason I don't have any keys logged in the `for...in` loop from the `Object.prototype` object is because all of them have the `enumerable: false` data property set. So I tried to override the configuration:

```js
const fromEntries = Object.fromEntries; // a random non-enumerable method
Object.defineProperty(Object, "fromEntries", {
  value: fromEntries,
  enumerable: true,
});
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Object, 'fromEntries'));
// { value: [Function: fromEntries], writable: true, enumerable: true, configurable: true }
for (const key in person1) {
  console.log(key);
}
// name
// age
// sex
```

The problem is, I still don't have the 'fromEntries' method logged into my `for...in` loop. Am I making wrong assumptions on how the prototype chain works? Or is it because the `Object.prototype` is non-configurable or something like that? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You’re changing it on Object, the class (as opposed to Object.prototype) which isn’t in person1’s inheritance chain. Object _instances_ don’t have a built-in fromEntries method.

Answer (score 0):

`fromEntries` is a method on `Object` itself - it's not on `Object.prototype`, so no object will ever have `Object.fromEntries` in its prototype chain, under normal circumstances.

Similarly, setting a property onto Parent does not put it into the prototype chain:

```js
function Parent(name) {
  this.name = name;
}
Parent.prototype.sex = "Male";
function Child(name, age) {
  Parent.call(this, name);
  this.age = age;
}
Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);


Parent.STATIC_PROPERTY = 'static property';
const c = new Child('somename', 5);
for (const prop in c) {
  console.log(prop);
}
```

If the method was on `Object.prototype`, it *would* be in the prototype chain, and you could overwrite the descriptor so that it'd be visible when iterating over plain objects. Here's an example of doing that for `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty`:

```js
function Parent(name) {
  this.name = name;
}
Parent.prototype.sex = "Male";
function Child(name, age) {
  Parent.call(this, name);
  this.age = age;
}
Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);

const { hasOwnProperty } = Object.prototype;
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "hasOwnProperty", {
  value: hasOwnProperty,
  enumerable: true,
});
for (const key in new Child('name', 5)) {
  console.log(key);
}
```

Or, slightly simpler:

```js
function Parent(name) {
  this.name = name;
}
Parent.prototype.sex = "Male";
function Child(name, age) {
  Parent.call(this, name);
  this.age = age;
}
Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);

const { hasOwnProperty } = Object.prototype;
delete Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty = hasOwnProperty;
for (const key in new Child('name', 5)) {
  console.log(key);
}
```

(not that overwriting native prototypes should be done - this is just for illustration of the mechanics in play)